# loop for each element of np array from zero to acutal value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to loop for each element value of np array l from 0 to its acutal value using it for further calculations. E.g. at coordinate l[50,50] the value is 359.59. I want to cast it to an integer (359) and use a loop to iterate from 0 to 359.

At the moment I get an error for the for loop: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

Is it possible to solve this with an for-loop or even to vectorize it?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 90, 90)
y = np.linspace(0,120,120)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

l = np.zeros((120, 90))
m = np.zeros((120,90))

l = np.sqrt(X**3 + Y)
print(l)
print(l.shape)

for x in int(l):
    m = x*Y
```

Comment: If you want to access element l(50,50)

You can do
```
for x in range(int(l[50][50])):
  <rest of code here>
```

But it still does not make sense to me what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Why are you withholding useful information!  Where in the #&@$@ did the error occur?  If I had to guess, it's the `int(l)` expression, where `l` in a numpy array.  But I shouldn't have to guess!

Comment: Yes, the l in int(l) inside the for loop causes the error